# Not unique table/alias?

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

I get this error: Not unique table/alias: 'postcode'

```
"SELECT sub.city AS city, sub.postalcode AS postalcode FROM 
(SELECT postcode.city AS city,  customers.postalcode AS postalcode, COUNT(customers.postalcode) AS postcode_numbers
FROM orders, postcode 
INNER JOIN customers ON orders.userID = customers.ID 
INNER JOIN postcode ON customers.postalcode = postcode.city 
GROUP BY customers.postalcode) sub 
WHERE sub.postcode_numbers > 3";
```

Comment: It’s pretty obvious... “FROM orders, postcode ... INNER JOIN postcode”

Answer (score 0):

```
Remove postcode  table in the from statement   
 SELECT sub.city AS city, sub.postalcode AS postalcode FROM 
    (SELECT postcode.city AS city,  customers.postalcode AS postalcode, COUNT(customers.postalcode) AS postcode_numbers
    FROM orders
    INNER JOIN customers ON orders.userID = customers.ID 
    INNER JOIN postcode ON customers.postalcode = postcode.city 
    GROUP BY customers.postalcode) sub 
    WHERE sub.postcode_numbers > 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You have `postcode` in both your `from` clause and your second `join` clause. Remove it from the `from` clause and you should be OK:

```
SELECT sub.city AS city, sub.postalcode AS postalcode FROM 
(SELECT postcode.city AS city,  customers.postalcode AS postalcode, COUNT(customers.postalcode) AS postcode_numbers
FROM orders -- Removed postcode from here 
INNER JOIN customers ON orders.userID = customers.ID 
INNER JOIN postcode ON customers.postalcode = postcode.city 
GROUP BY customers.postalcode) sub 
WHERE sub.postcode_numbers > 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using postcode table in both FROM clause and and INNER JOIN clause, neither of which have an alias, when you do an INNER JOIN you don't need to have that table in the FROM clause, and other way around of course.

If you want to join the tables in FROM clause you would do something like this:

```
SELECT
    sub.city AS city, sub.postalcode AS postalcode 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         postcode.city AS city,  customers.postalcode AS postalcode, 
         COUNT(customers.postalcode) AS postcode_numbers
     FROM 
         orders, postcode 
     INNER JOIN 
         customers ON orders.userID = customers.ID 
     --INNER JOIN postcode ON customers.postalcode = postcode.city
     WHERE 
         postcode.city = customers.postalcode
     GROUP BY 
         customers.postalcode) sub 
WHERE 
    sub.postcode_numbers > 3;
```

So basically you would lose the INNER JOIN postcode... line

The other way to do this is to use only the INNER JOIN clause, which is my preferred way. To do this you only need to lose the postcode in FROM clause, like so:

```
SELECT 
    sub.city AS city, sub.postalcode AS postalcode 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         postcode.city AS city,  customers.postalcode AS postalcode, 
         COUNT(customers.postalcode) AS postcode_numbers
     FROM 
         orders 
     INNER JOIN 
         customers ON orders.userID = customers.ID 
     INNER JOIN 
         postcode ON customers.postalcode = postcode.city
     GROUP BY 
         customers.postalcode) sub 
WHERE 
    sub.postcode_numbers > 3;
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can write this as:

```
SELECT p.city,  c.postalcode , COUNT(*) AS num_orders
FROM orders o JOIN
     customers c
     ON o.userID = c.ID JOIN
     postcode p
     ON c.postalcode = p.city 
GROUP BY p.city, c.postalcode
HAVING COUNT(*) > 3;
```

It is unclear whether you want one row per `city` or per `city`/`postalcode`.  This assumes the latter.  If you want one row per `city`, remove `postalcode` from *both* the `SELECT` and the `GROUP BY`.

Notes:

- *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.  That is your specific problem.
- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.
- The unaggregated columns in the `SELECT` should match the `GROUP BY` keys.
- A subquery is not necessary.